# Associate values between two lists with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have to List of items of same datamodel

**List A**

```
ID  Name Address
1  aaa  address1
2  bbb  address2
3  ccc  address3
```

**myList**

```
ID Name Address
1
2
3
```

i have to check the master list with the ID and get the other values from that list A for corresponding ID

How i can do this in linq c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in following way...........

```
List<Person> newList = (from master in listMaster
                        from list in myList
                        where master.id == list.id
                        select master).ToList<Person>();
```

newList contain Person info which has id in myList...............

Comment: You can omit the type in `ToList`

Answer (score 2):

This will give you all the values from List A for all the ids that are in myList:

```
var res = from a in ListA
where myList.contains(a.ID)
select a
```

Comment: Sure, but "get the other values ... for corresponding ID"

Comment: I thought "other values"  mean Name and Address, and that this should be done to all IDs in myList

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by linq as below:

```
 myList = myList.Select(x=>listA.FirstOrDefault(y=>y.ID == x.ID)??x).ToList()
```

Efficient way is sorting and comparing elements, which is O(n logn) and if elements in both list are sorted it's O(n):

```
listA = listA.OrderBy(x=>x.ID).ToList();
myList = myList.OrderBy(x=>x.ID).ToList(); 

int index = 0;
foreach(var item in listA)
{
   while(index < myList.Count && myList[index].ID < listA.ID)
      index++;
   if (index > myList.Count)
     break;

   if (myList[index].ID = item.ID)
   {
       myList[index] = item;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller, pass the id

```
public ActionResult ListController(int id)  
{  
    //process code

    //syntax would be database.items.Select(list => list.ID = id) for checking with the master list for corresponding IDs

}
```

Hope this gives you direction.